# getting which dom element is returned?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, firebug

i am writing some JavaScript code and i test the code in console or via an alert msg i get the following text as return value.

if i use this code:

```
     alert($("#images img"));
```

i get:

```
   [object object]
```

how can i get the name of the tag, ie, if its an image tag or li so i know it is being targeted correctly.

i use firefox and chrome..is there a way i can locate this under the developer tools or firebug...if so then under which section?

Comment: [Learn how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [properly **debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging).

Answer (score 2):

Avoid `alert` for debugging as it only outputs strings, use the console:

```
console.log($("#images img")[0].tagName)
```

You can access the DOM element of any jQuery collection with bracket syntax, like an array.

If you use `alert(obj)` you get `[object Object]` which is an object's `toString` output, as `alert` will coerce anything into a string. If you use `console.log(obj)` you'll see the object as a real object.

Comment: Amusing.  You tell them to use the console to look at more than just strings and then you recommend they log a string `$("#images img")[0].tagName`.

Comment: OP will figure out how to log the object if needed, the fact still remains, use console, not alert.

Comment: I don't disagree with using `console.log()` (actually I generally find it more useful to use the debugger), but I just thought your answer was strangely worded which you could fix by explaining what the OP would see if they used `console.log()` on an object.

Answer (score 1):

For get the tag name you can use `prop()` method.

```
$("#images img").prop("tagName");
```

For put the script into debugger you can use the `console` tab on Chrome,

**How to get the console tab on chrome?**

Use the keyboard shortcut Command `- Option - J (Mac) or Control -Shift -J (Windows/Linux).`

```
Select View > Developer > JavaScript Console.
```

More information about [**Console Tab**](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console)

Answer (score 0):

If you want more information about the tag you can do something like this:

```
console.log($("#images img")[0].outerHTML)
```

Or if you might have more than one item:

```
$("#images img").each(function(){
    console.log(this.outerHTML);
});
```

Which will print the below to the [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/logging)/[Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) console:

```
<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/5e188e06ccdee56a568db3c383fa0f3d?s=24&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG" alt="" class="avatar-me js-avatar-me" width="24" height="24">
```